# Update records greater than today's date and time for table where DueDate and DueTime fields are different columns

Tags: mysql

I've a table that looks somewhat like this

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    UserAction VARCHAR(20),
    JoiningDate DATETIME,
    JoiningTime TIME
);
```

And it consists of following records:

```
UserAction  JoiningDate          JoiningTime  
----------  -------------------  -------------
Pending     2018-01-14 00:00:00  20:00:00
Pending     2018-01-15 00:00:00  16:00:00     
Pending     2018-01-16 00:00:00  16:00:00     
Pending     2018-01-16 00:00:00  20:00:00     
Pending     2018-01-17 00:00:00  16:00:00
```

Now I want to update all records where:

1. `JoiningDate` is greater than `2018-01-16`
2. But if Joining date is equal to `2018-01-16` then `JoiningTime` is `18:00:00` or above

This is my final desired output:

```
UserAction  JoiningDate          JoiningTime  
----------  -------------------  -------------
Pending     2018-01-14 00:00:00  20:00:00     
Pending     2018-01-15 00:00:00  16:00:00     
Pending     2018-01-16 00:00:00  16:00:00     
DONE        2018-01-16 00:00:00  20:00:00     
DONE        2018-01-17 00:00:00  16:00:00
```

Currently I've to write two different queries to achieve this:

```
UPDATE foo SET UserAction = 'DONE' WHERE JoiningDate > '2018-01-16 00:00:00';
UPDATE foo SET UserAction = 'DONE' WHERE JoiningDate = '2018-01-16 00:00:00' AND JoiningTime >= '18:00:00';
```

and it works fine. My question is, is there any way to achieve the same using just one query?

Comment: The last record of your expected output contradicts your problem statement.

Comment: `Pending     2018-01-17 00:00:00  16:00:00` <-- the joining time is less than `18:00:00` yet you said you want this record updated to `DONE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's because in that record the date is more than '2018-01-16 00:00:00'. I've updated my question one more time, please see if it makes it any clearer.

Comment: Hi Jarvis.  It seems more clear now, thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE foo
SET UserAction = 'DONE'
WHERE
    JoiningDate > '2018-01-16' OR
    (JoiningDate = '2018-01-16' AND JoiningTime >= '18:00:00');
```

This literally matches your requirement to update all records where the joining date is greater than `2018-01-16`, or the joining date is `2018-01-16` and the joining time is `18:00:00` or later.  Your queries actually do something different, but I have answered based on what you wrote.

Comment: Let's say I've one more record which I don't want to be updated `"Pending", '2018-01-14 00:00:00', '20:00:00'` because in this the date is smaller than `2018-01-16`. This solution updates even this record so it won't be helpful :(

Comment: @Jarvis Then that would completely invalidate both your question and my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of question is confusing. I've added the final output that I wish to achieve. I'm getting this output using 2 different update queries that I've mentioned in question but I want to ask if it's possible to make them as one.

Comment: Jarvis your question could not be any less clear.  Please tell us your logic.

Comment: my apologies. I've updated my question and removed all redundant info. Please see if it's clear now.

Comment: Maybe specifying a date type, removing timestamp, will be better:


`
UPDATE foo
SET UserAction = 'DONE'
WHERE
    DATE(JoiningDate) > '2018-01-16' OR
    (DATE(JoiningDate) = '2018-01-16' AND JoiningTime >= '18:00:00');
`

Comment: @RafaelMori The literal `2018-01-16` means that date at precisely midnight, which is the same as `2018-01-16 00:00:00`.  Regarding using `DATE`, it would preclude the possibility of using an index on `JoiningDate`, so I think the way I wrote it is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
update  `Foo`
SET UserAction = 'Done'
where date(JoiningDate) > '2018-01-16' AND JoiningTime >= '18:00:00'
```

Is this your requirement? And why do you need JoiningDate = '2018-01-16' AND JoiningTime >= '18:00:00'

Comment: The last record of the expected output is `DONE` and yet has a joining time of `16:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe specifying a date type, removing timestamp, will be better:

```
UPDATE Foo 
SET UserAction = 'DONE' 
WHERE DATE(JoiningDate) > '2018-01-16' 
OR (DATE(JoiningDate) = '2018-01-16' AND JoiningTime >= '18:00:00');
```